# Sql Server Service Broker Conversation Groups

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Can someone explain conversation groups in service broker?

Currently, I'm using service broker to send messages from one SQL server to another. On the sending server, I'm trying to correlate the messages so they are processed in serial on the receiving side. Based on the documentation, conversation groups seem to be a perfect fit for this, but on the receiving server, the messages get assigned to a different conversation group from the one I specified when sending the message.

I've search around the web and saw that this behavior seems to be intended (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/baf48074-6804-43ab-844a-cb28a6dce02b/), but then I'm confused about the usefulness of the syntax from (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178624.aspx)

```
WAITFOR( 
  GET CONVERSATION GROUP @conversation_group_id FROM [dbo].[ReceiveQueue]
)
```

If the conversation group doesn't come across with the message from the sender and messages sent with the same conversation group id don't have the same conversation group id on the receive side, what's the point of the code above?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Conversation groups are a local primitve used for locking. Messages within a conversation group have no order guarantees, and conversation groups do not flow across the wire.

The message order is guaranteed by Service Broker within a conversation. So to preserve the order of corrleated messages in processing, send them on the same conversation.

Conversation groups are needed for groupping a set of conversations that are related to each other. Both `GET CONVERSATION GROUP` and `RECEIVE` verbs guarantee that they will lock an entire converstaion group, thus preventing any other thread from processing related messages. For example consider a traveling site. It receives a message with a request to book a holiday package. As a result it initiates a conversation with a hotel booking service and sends a request to reserve a room, it initiates a conversation with an airline reservation service and asks for travel reservation, it initiates a conversation with a car rental agency service and asks for a car reservation. These three new conversation it created are all in the same group with the initial conversation that the request was received on (the application has used the `WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION` clause of [BEGIN DIALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187377.aspx) on all 3 of them). It then commits and proceed to process the messages in the queue. Later responses from these 3 correlated requests start comming in, at pretty much random times. Say the hotel resposnse comes in first. The message gets picked up by the applicaiton and it goes ahead to update the status of the request with the response from the hotel. At the same time, the airline response comes in. If another thread would be allowed to pick it up, it would try to update the status of the *same* request, thus resulting in blocking or even deadlock against the thread that is processing the hotel response. When the hotel response is processed, the thread commits and thus unlocks the whole conversation group, allowing for any thread (including itself) to pick up the airline response and process it.

Comment: Thanks. That's about the best explanation I could find on the web. Maybe it's just me but the Microsoft MSDN documentation on this feature seems very ambiguous. Any suggestions on how to serialize the processing of messages on the receive queue? I'm sending messages out that can potentially update a single record on the receive side. These messages are from different sources and as such really can't be part of the same conversation. I need to make sure that the messages that relate to each other on the receive side are processed in order and in serial.

Comment: The target can group conversations using using MOVE CONVERSATION. It can then move any 'new' conversation into it's proper group. Another alternative is to reverse the dialog initiaton: the 'back-end' initates the dialog(s) (and hence control their grouping on his side) and the 'front end' sends on the *target* endpoint of dialogs. If the back-end cannot know the fornt end names/location the 'initiation' can be triggered by the front-end sending a message with the meaning 'subscribe me please at this address'. The proper solution depends on specifics of your scenario. Send me an email.

Comment: Yeah, the move conversation approach is what we're currently looking into. The concern is that since move conversation locks the target conversation group and getting messages by their conversation group locks the associated conversation group, we might get into a deadlock situation. We're in the middle of a POC trying to resolve that concern. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Indeed MOVE has a potential to deadlock. Kudos for seeing this during analysis. I'm a bit concerned that you plan to use GET CONVERSATION GROUP and not straight RECEIVE. The sole reason GET exists is to alloow the pattern GET GROUP/lookup state on group value/RECEIVE WHERE group, but frankly I see little use for it and I actually regret GET CONVERSATION was allowed into the language. A pattern like RECEIVE NO WHERE/lookup state/process is just as easy to code and actually more efficient imho.

Comment: @Remus - This is a great explanation.  Thanks.  I'm having trouble with applying it.  My understanding is that by specifying a `RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP` on send, a `WAITFOR (RECEIVE TOP (1) * FROM Q)` within a transaction will lock the conversation group from all other transactions, until the transaction completes.  Instead, I'm seeing that the RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP specified is not what is received, nor is it 1:1 mapped to some new receive-side UUID (that is, the conversation group id changes with every receive, since you say that "conversation groups do not flow across the wire")

Comment: @Jason: please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - Ok, [This is the one we're working on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434464/sql-server-service-broker), my co-worker is the OP