# Multiple conversations on Service Broker

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

Let say I have two instances of the same app interacting with a backend service in Service Broker. How can each instance know to handle only conversations it initiated and ignore the rest? If I recall correctly, every RECEIVE will remove the message from the queue.

Here's an example:

```
-- Assume the SquareService return the square of the number sent to it

-- Instance 1
BEGIN DIALOG @Conversation1
    FROM SERVICE InitService
    TO SERVICE 'SquareService'
    ON CONTRACT (MyContract)
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @Conversation1 MESSAGE TYPE MyMessageType('1');

-- Instance 2
BEGIN DIALOG @Conversation2
    ...;
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @Conversation2 MESSAGE TYPE MyMessageType('2');
```

Now who should I write the `RECEIVE` statement so that Instance 1 will correctly get 1 and Instance 2 get 4 back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using a Conversation Group.
Is this not sufficient for your needs when Receiving the messages?
-> using GET CONVERSATION GROUP and RECEIVE together 
you can read more about it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166131%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
and also here [Sql Server Service Broker Conversation Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314050/sql-server-service-broker-conversation-groups)

Comment: Thanks and full marks for you answer. Microsoft documentation is so poor on the topic that I don't even know what the `CONVERSATION GROUP` is for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an `InitQueue` associated with your `InitService`.  You can use a `WHERE` clause with `RECEIVE` to listen for messages on the same conversation:

```
WAITFOR (RECEIVE @response = CONVERT(xml, message_body)
    FROM InitQueue -- InitService setup to use InitQueue?
    WHERE conversation_handle = @Conversation1
```